# Transform text on Y axis without moving underline?

Tags: html, css, transform

I'm trying to move text when text is hovered Y pixels on Y axis. What What is more I want to move just text, without underline. Any ideas how to achieve this?

```
#blah:hover {
color:red;
transform: translateY(-20px);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xUa8P/

Comment: To clarify, when text is hovered over, you want to to be shifted 20px on y-axis (up).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this? it doesn't use `transform`, but accomplishes the same thing.

We move the text upwards by a certain amount (`3px` in this case). To prevent the "underline"  border moving up as well, we add a bottom padding of the same amount.

```
#blah:hover {
    position: relative;
    top: -3px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c7LvB/

Answer (score 0):

you can use border-bottom and even use other transform properties for its fun.

```
<p><u class="udrln"><span class="rotate">text wich would rotate</span></u>
<u class="udrln"><span class="translate">text wich would translate</span></u></p>
```

```
.udrln {
  border-bottom:1px solid;
  line-height:0.8em;
  display:inline-block;
}
.rotate {
  display:inline-block;
  transform:rotate(-5deg);
  transform-origin:left;
  text-shadow:0 0 ;
}
.translate {
  display:inline-block;
  transform: translateY(-20px);
}
```

demo : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/ImJjq

Comment: All true, but doesn't help answer the question

Comment: there is no other way than to fake the underline than to draw it inside on an inline-boxe growiing with text,  isn't ?

Comment: That's the way I would approach it too, but the OP needed the translation to happen on hover.

Comment: oki, what about the op to add the :hover himself ? transaley/translatex are equals to relative positionning with coordonnates if that's your point :) , cheers